# Create a ByteBuf in Netty 4.0

Tags: java, netty, nio

Two simple questions, which I am not able to solve by reading the documentation:

1. I have a `byte[]`

   - How can i convert it to a `ByteBuf`?
2. I have a NIO `ByteBuffer`

   - How can i convert it to a `ByteBuf`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The [documentation](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html) seems pretty clear to me:

> **Creation of a buffer**
>
> It is recommended to create a new buffer using the helper methods in [Unpooled](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html) rather than calling an individual implementation's constructor.

Then in `Unpooled`, you've got options of wrapping or copying. For example:

- [`Unpooled.copiedBuffer(ByteBuffer)`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#copiedBuffer%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29)
- [`Unpooled.copiedBuffer(byte[])`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#copiedBuffer%28byte%5B%5D%29)
- [`Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(ByteBuffer)`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#wrappedBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer))
- [`Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(byte[])`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#wrappedBuffer%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Choose whichever method is appropriate based on whether you want changes made in the returned `ByteBuf` to be passed through to the original byte array/buffer.

Comment: Example: Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { 0x0D, 0X0A })