# Efficient way to convert io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf to java.nio.ByteBuffer

Tags: java, netty, bytebuffer

I came across this query: [Create a ByteBuf in Netty 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088065/create-a-bytebuf-in-netty-4-0-0-beta1) about conversion from byte[] to ByteBuf and ByteBuffer to ByteBuf. I was curious to know about the conversion the other way:

io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf to java.nio.ByteBuffer

and how to do it efficiently, with minimal/no copying? I did some reading and with some trial and error I found this inefficient way of converting it (with two copies):

```
// io.netty.handler.codec.http.FullHttpRequest fullHttpRequest;
ByteBuf conByteBuf = fullHttpRequest.content ();                  
int numReadBytes = conByteBuf.readableBytes ();
conBytes = new byte[numReadBytes];
conByteBuf .readBytes (conBytes);                                // First Copy
ByteBuffer conByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate (conBytes.length);
conByteBuffer.put (conByteBuf);                                  // Second Copy
```

My question is, can we avoid one or both the copies and make the internal buffer of ByteBuffer to use the internal buffer of ByteBuf.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can at least use `ByteBuffer.wrap()` to avoid the second copying.

Comment: Can we still avoid the first copy?

Comment: It seems Dev's response below will help eliminate even that.

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to use [ByteBuf.nioBuffers()](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#nioBuffers%28%29). Which will return a view of the `ByteBuf` as an array of ByteBuffer objects.

In most cases this array will only have one element, but in some of the more complicated implementations of `ByteBuf` there may be multiple underlying ByteBuffer objects and `ByteBuf.nioBuffers()` can return them as-is instead of merging them as would a call to `ByteBuf.nioBuffer()`.

You can tell ahead of time what the array length will be by using `ByteBuf.nioBufferCount()`

Comment: This doesn't address when it is backed by a byte[]

Comment: @Dev, When you use `ByteBuf.nioBuffers()` or `ByteBuf.nioBuffer()` to return a view of the ByteBuf as an array of ByteBuffer objects or a single ByteBuffer object, what happens if you were to release the ByteBuf? It appears that problems will occur with the created ByteBuffer object when this happens since the ByteBuf and ByteBuffer share the underlying data.

Comment: So `ByteBuf.nioBuffer()` automatically merges them into one? I could just call this instead of iterating through the array in `nioBuffers()`?

Answer (score 2):

Not particularly efficient but doing the trick:

```java
public static ByteBuffer toNioBuffer(ByteBuf buffer) {
    if (buffer.isDirect()) {
        return buffer.nioBuffer();
    }
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableBytes()];
    buffer.getBytes(buffer.readerIndex(), bytes);
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
}
```