# Dose GWT support netty ByteBuf?

Tags: java, netty, nio, bytebuffer

In my project, I only use nio bytebuffer,because gwt support this, I wander, dose gwt support netty ByteBuf ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.25.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Currently, I don't have gwt env, but I hope this project support gwt.

BTW, bytebuffer and bytebuf is easy to conver to each other by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305543/1870054).If the internal of bytebuf just use bytebuffer, so, there will be no problem under gwt.

Dose any one can test this ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know GWT only supports ByteBuffer as this is part of Java itself. ByteBuf is a class which is part of Netty.

Comment: netty-buffer is a sperate module.ByteBuf is more friendly than ByteBuffer.It's not bind to netty