# how to convert File object to Netty ByteBuffer

Tags: java, netty

Is there a way I can get netty ByteBuf from a java File object? I am trying to use Custom [Snappy](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/compression/Snappy.java) class to validate checksum. Below is my code where I'd like to get `File` object in `bytebuf` variable.

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;

File file = new File("boot.zip");
ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.buffer(128);
byteBuf.writeBytes(new FileInputStream(file));
int expectedChecksum = Snappy.calculateChecksum(byteBuf);
logger.info("checksum = "+expectedChecksum);

boolean checksumValid = true;
try {       
    CustomSnappy.validateChecksum(expectedChecksum, byteBuf);
} catch(DecompressionException e) {
    checksumValid = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.error("DecompressionException in checksum calculation " + e);            
} catch(Exception e) {
    checksumValid = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.error("Exception in checksum calculation " + e);
}
```

I used Unpooled.buffer(128) but it gives me `No signature of method :io.netty.buffer.UnpooledHeapByteBuf.writeBytes() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.FileInputStream) values: [java.io.FileInputStream@28b6520b]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `ByteBuf#writeBytes(InputStream)`. This should work, but I did not test it.

```
ByteBuf buffer = // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15088238/834
buffer.writeBytes(new FileInputStream(file), file.length());
```

See http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#writeBytes(java.io.InputStream,%20int)

The documentation shows how to create a new `ByteBuf`: http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html

Comment: I get cannot create `ByteBuf` object from abstract type

Comment: Updated the answer with links to the official documentation and a good answer on SO.

Comment: but I cannot find anything to use with File object in your link.

Comment: Of course not, you have to create a new `ByteBuf`, then write the bytes from your file into the buffer, most likely with code like I tried to provide.

Comment: I used `Unpooled.buffer(128)` but it gives me `No signature of method: io.netty.buffer.UnpooledHeapByteBuf.writeBytes() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.FileInputStream) values: [java.io.FileInputStream@28b6520b]` exception

Comment: You should add more code and the new exceptions to your question.

Comment: As documented, there is no `writeBytes` method accepting one parameter, `java.io.InputStream`, only. This answer is confusing without deeply reading and understanding the official document.

Comment: `writeBytes` takes length as int `int  writeBytes(InputStream in, int length)`

Answer (score 6):

You can created a MappedByteBuf from a FileChannel and wrap it in ByteBuffer via Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(..).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how to "create a `MappedByteBuf` from a `FileChannel` and wrap it in `ByteBuffer` via `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(..)`":

```
    try {
        File file = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, file.length());

        ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(mappedByteBuffer);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDK 1.7, the class of `java.nio.file.Files` could make it easy with amount of static methods.

```
ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(Files.readAllBytes(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/requests/overPackageRequest").getFile()).toPath()));
```

Comment: `Files.readAllBytes` cannot deal with files that are over `Integer.MAX_VALUE` bytes